# Read and Compare 2 CSV files on a row and column basis

Tags: python, excel, csv

I have two CSV files. data.csv and data2.csv.

I would like to first of Strip the two data files down to the data I am interested in.  I have figured this part out with data.csv.  I would then like to compare by row making sure that if a row is missing to add it.

Next I want to look at column 2.  If there is a value there then I want to write to column 3 if there is data in column 3 then write to 4, etc.

My current program looks like sow.  Need some guidance

Oh and I am using Python V3.4

```
    __author__ = 'krisarmstrong'

#!/usr/bin/python

import csv

searched = ['aircheck', 'linkrunner at', 'onetouch at']


def find_group(row):
    """Return the group index of a row
        0 if the row contains searched[0]
        1 if the row contains searched[1]
        etc
        -1 if not found
    """
    for col in row:
        col = col.lower()
        for j, s in enumerate(searched):
            if s in col:
                return j
        return -1


inFile = open('data.csv')
reader = csv.reader(inFile)
inFile2 = open('data2.csv')
reader2 = csv.reader(inFile2)
outFile = open('data3.csv', "w")
writer = csv.writer(outFile, delimiter=',', quotechar='"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)

header = next(reader)
header2 = next(reader2)


"""Built a list of items to sort. If row 12 contains 'LinkRunner AT' (group 1),
    one stores a triple (1, 12, row)
    When the triples are sorted later, all rows in group 0 will come first, then
    all rows in group 1, etc.
"""

stored = []
writer.writerow([header[0], header[3]])

for i, row in enumerate(reader):
    g = find_group(row)
    if g >= 0:
        stored.append((g, i, row))
stored.sort()

for g, i, row in stored:
    writer.writerow([row[0], row[3]])

inFile.close()
outFile.close()
```

Comment: So what is the problem? errors or something else?

Comment: Marcin,  the above code works. no errors.  I am wanting to add another piece in which I compare 2 CSV files.  If a row is missing from the first CSV file add it.  If Column 2 is full add the data to column 3 if 2 and 3 are full add the data to column 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps try:

```
import csv
with open('some.csv', 'rb') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    for row in reader:
        col1.append(row[0])
        col2.append(row[1])

for i in xrange(len(col1))
    if col1[i] == '':
        #thing to do if there is nothing for col1
    if col2[i] == '':
        #thing to do if there is nothing for col2
```

This is a start at "making sure that if a row is missing to add it".

Comment: If I understand this correctly this would be to add aanother function comparing the some.csv to the other data file correct?